# Automate creation of branch + pull-request

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, git, github

I have a repository (call it repo-X) of shell.nix files that define development environments for a number of separate projects (call them project-A, project-B).

When one of the projects releases a new version, I run a suite of automated tests in repo-X for the relevant shell.nix file, and if all goes well, I increment the version number in that file to match the new version of the project it supports.

I'd like to automate this process. I'm using Jenkins and GitHub to *build* PRs, but I'm not sure how I'd use CI to *author* a feature branch and create a corresponding PR.

I'm having a hard time even finding references/ideas, but maybe I'm searching for the wrong terms. What tooling should I look into for this?

Comment: I do this but with Bitbucket instead of Github.  Basically I just wrote down the steps that a dev would normally take to create a branch, update it, and open a PR, and put those steps in a Jenkinsfile.  The only difference is that Jenkins has to use the Bitbucket/Github API instead of the web interface to do the PR steps.  As long as the original process was CI-compatible, the automated process will be too.

Comment: i am using curl + github api to automatically create pull requests in a Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: in your scenario, I'll probably have project-A builds trigger project-X with parameters inside a jenkins pipeline. as you'll need to do the same thing in many repos, a shared pipeline library would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You want a [RCS/VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_Control_System) that handles the version incrementally for you. I'm not sure how this relates to CI as the idea is to [Continuously Integrate](https://stackify.com/continuous-delivery-git-jenkins/) instead of spawning more branches. I'm not sure what you're using for your PR's, so I'll use Atlassian Bitbucket as an example. In the response to pushing up a new branch you get back the url for creating a PR which has an [API which you can call to create your PR](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/).
Git commands will do the branching for you:

```
# Get the latest description, usually based on tags : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging
$branchName = git describe
# Checkout the new branch 
git checkout -b $branchName
# Push up the branch to origin
git push --set-upstream origin feature/$branchName
```

It's best to have a firm grasp of git when dealing with VCS. 
* https://try.github.io/ 
* https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics

Comment: For context, a developer other than me may be developing/merging a branch to project-A, but I'm the only one maintaining the files in repo-X. I'm looking not to offload that work to other developers, but rather to a script that performs a trivial update (e.g. text-replacement), commits the change to a branch, and creates a PR. I'd still want to manually review the PR, rather than trust 100% in the update script.

Comment: Ok, not seeing where I mentioned that this would resolve the PR for you? GitHub api can create the PR for you (see [create a pull request](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request)

Answer (score 0):

I am now starting to use the multi-branch pipeline and it looks really promising as it builds every branch that contains changes and a Jenkinsfile.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Multibranch+Plugin